# Unity Augmented Reality Scene Inside Native Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to integrate augmented reality Unity 3d scene inside native android.Like when I press button from native ANdroid it will open Augmented reality camera of Unity 3d scene.

I have successfully combined both but problem is there,Whenever I open Augmented Reality Scene camera of my mobilephone not started and AR not working.
 I am using ARCore for surface tracing.

Comment: did you ask for permissions to use the camera of the phone in the unity app?

Comment: yes I have given camera permission

Comment: DllNotFoundException: UnityARCore

Comment: It seems there is an error in the installation of ARCore, try to reinstall the plugin in unity, and test the scene with debug mode, check: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/enable-arcore

Comment: ARCore is running fine and targeting surface whenever I made only Unity Build.Error occur only when I connect it to android app.